# Run an external application inside a qwidget

Tags: qt, qt4

How can we embed an external application inside a QWidget?

I have tried same using QX11EmbedContainer but getting error "XEvent has not been declared".

I have tried below mentioned code ('this' represents a qwidget class reference )

```
     QX11EmbedContainer * container = new QX11EmbedContainer(this);
     container->show();

     QProcess * process = new QProcess(container);
     QString executable("\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe\"");

     process->start(executable);

     this->show();
```

container object i am trying to add to current tab of tabwidget object in which i want to run some external application(Application1).
This is my code

```
     QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget;

     /* Trying to add external appllication to a tab of tabwidget object */
     QX11EmbedContainer * container = new QX11EmbedContainer(tabWidget->currentWidget());
     container->show();

     QProcess * process = new QProcess(container);
     QString executable("/home/abhishek/practice/Applicaion1");

     process->start(executable);
```

Application1 gets executed but in a seperate window but i want it to run in my tab

Comment: QX11EmbedContainer is for XWindows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QX11EmbedContainer` only works on X11 (e.g., on Linux). From the looks of it, you're trying to do this on Windows.

I'm not very familiar with using Qt on Windows, but it looks like the equivalent functionality is provided by the [ActiveQt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/activeqt.html) module. You might be able to accomplish something like this within that framework.

Comment: I have tried the same on Linux also (RHEL 6) but its not working.
In linux the path i have given is

QString executable("/home/abhishek/practice/Applicaion1");

When i run my code, Application1 gets executed from my current application but it runs in a seperate window.
I want it to be embedded inside my current QWidget.

Comment: I see. Then it sounds like your code sample above is incomplete -- what do you do with the `container` widget? It doesn't look like it's added to a layout or as a child of an existing widget, which is why it would appear in its own window.

Comment: container i am adding to a tab of a tabwidget object as defined in above code

Comment: I have the same problem, I need also to run an external application inside a qwidget - cvan you please share me what was your way to do that?

Comment: @Abhishek: Can you please share your solution, or give some pointers? I am having a similar requirement, to launch a CLI (Command Line Interface)based executable inside a tabwidget. I can launch it as a separate process, in a separate window, but having it inside the QTabWidget would be really nice. Can you please help? Thanks