# Embeding a Game inside a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Recently I have taken up a project in which I want to embed a game (written in C++) inside a Qt Application.

I have done a little bit of research into how this is done, but I haven't been able to come up with any definitive answers. The closest question I have been able to come across is this one:
[Run an external application inside a qwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679464/run-an-external-application-inside-a-qwidget?rq=1)

Unfortunately, the person found his solution, and did not post how it was done.
Instead of replying to an old question(and because of lack of rep, not being able to leave a comment), I thought I would ask here.

Currently I have a Button set up on my project that is calling my "EmbedGame" function, which looks like this currently:

```
void MainUI::EmbedGame(){

    QProcess * process = new QProcess(ui->wgtGame);
    QString Executable("\"C:\\my\\game\\path\\game.exe\"");

    process->start(Executable);
}
```

I am programming on Windows 7 64-bit, using the Qt Creator IDE.
I am quite new to C++ and just started Qt recently, but I am coming from programming in Java for a very long time (I am a very confident Java Programmer).

This program does not require to be cross platform if this is any help.

The problem I am facing is the game is executing, but it is not embedded inside my "wgtGame" QWidget. it is opening in its own window.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have tried my best with my limited knowledge of Qt, and haven't been able to work it out.

Thanks!
.::Kaden::.

Comment: If you had read the question accurately, you would have seen, that the solution applied only to X11 (Linuces, BSDs, ...).

Comment: Which is why I am asking for how to do it on windows, and also saying that NO solution was provided. He just said "I found the solution, thanks" and didn't elaborate as to how he achieved it.

Comment: Is the game something you have written, or are you trying to host 3rd party executables?

Comment: I have not written the game, but I know that it is written in C++ and uses DirectX for its graphics.

Comment: You can use the EnumThreadWindows winapi function on the process handle to get it's main window HWND, then set flags to make it a borderless child window, then see if you can embed it in an existing Qt widget, given it's HWND handle. Since all windows are children of the desktop window, it is certainly possible in theory to have one process window nested in another process window, in the sense that HWND's will be unique, but this is probably prohibited by the OS.